# Why was my edit suggestion rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12315171) to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563051/mpandroidchart-setting-chart-padding-offset). But one reviewer has rejected it. See the screenshot:

[image]

Every Android user knows that this is code for the **Android Chart**. So then why has the reviewer rejected this? I also mentioned "Code Improve" as the edit summary.

The edit has now entirely been rejected:

BoltClock chose "Reject and Edit", but what is different form my edit, removing the "thank you" portion.

[image]

Comment: The review process requires multiple reviewers, so your edit isn't completely rejected yet - it's just one person's opinion. It's likely the other reviewers decide in your favour - it seems like a straightforward decision

Comment: @Pekka웃 But It is `important` if the `second reviewer` is `same` as the `first one` then.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? At the moment, there is only one reviewer, correct?

Comment: I hope you're not putting any egregious code formatting in your edits - I'd outright reject for that simple reason.

Comment: The edit is also wrong. You're removing information: the 1 and the 2, listing the OP's **different** attempts at solutions.

Comment: @J.Steen in the `Question` the user say that he used the `Method` but all know that this is code. And Second thing if the `user` say this is method and we know that we have put it on `code block`.

Comment: And you haven't removed the noise and fluffs (thank you, salutations).

Comment: @J.Steen ` the noise and fluffs (thank you, salutations)` is there check it again.

Comment: Yes, it's there. That's the problem.

Comment: The review is correct, if harsh. The other option the reviewer could have taken is to improve your edit by doing what you didn't do.

Comment: @J.Steen if I remove in  `my pervious` edited post then `Reviewer` say that don't do it ?

Comment: [On *noise and fluffs*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) (cross-site).

Answer (score 11):

The review process requires multiple reviewers, so your edit isn't completely rejected yet - it's just one person's opinion.

However, as J. Steen pointed out, the reviewer may have rejected your edit because it could/should be improved:

- The OP deliberately added numbering to the two attempts they had tried. It should be preserved.
- When editing, salutations and "thank you"s should be removed. We're striving to be an encyclopedia rather than a forum, so we remove anything not directly related to the question. (One should **not** search for posts containing those things and edit only them, though.)

If future edits of yours get rejected, please do not be afraid to ask "why" here on Meta, even though the tone can be harsh and downvotes quick. Neither will impact your reputation.

Comment: that's mean `code improve` is `not important` but the importance is `remove thank you and so on`.

Comment: No - both are very important, but they should *happen in the same edit.* An edit should try to fix *all* the problems in a post.

Comment: ok now see the `other reviewer` how they can seen my edit.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you clarify? You mean how did the other user find your edit? There's special tools for it, the so called "review queues". They're available to users with more than 3000 points, I think.

Comment: Better yet - don't emphasise needlessly. There is *usually* no need to put anything in bold or italics.

Comment: @Pekka 웃 no I mean no `This is for only first Reviewer` will see the `Other Reviewer` what they say. ?

Comment: Yes, they will see what the other reviewer said.

Comment: By the way, I recommend using `block formatting` only for code, numbers and such! Use *italics* or **bold** for emphasis (when necessary - it isn't necessary often.)

Comment: @Harshad Other users can see your edit in a few ways. Your edits are visible from your profile page. They can also encounter them in the Suggested Edits review queue, as Pekka noted. Access to the Suggested Edits review queue is unlocked at 2000 points.

Comment: @Harshad see J. Steen's recommendations on how to improve the edit that I summarized in my answer. You could make the suggestion again (I think that should be possible) and implement those recommendations

Comment: @Pekka웃 Boltclock rejected and edited, so there are probably no items to fix left in that question.

Comment: @Pekka웃 if the `Reviewer` want that can `Approve and Edit`.

Comment: Yes - but then we wouldn't have had this discussion, and you wouldn't have learned about editing policies.