# Why was my edit adding official documentation rejected?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, rejected-edits

According to [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322832/6205782) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286202/contest-rejected-edit/286206#286206), this is the right place to get some feedback on an rejected edit I don't understand.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25258389) recent edit of mine, I added a link to the offciial documentation of a function that was recommended in the answer. My edit was however rejected by a 2-1 vote because:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

The closest post here on meta that I found is this [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333600/i-added-a-link-why-was-my-edit-rejected) where the community states that the added link was not directing to the official documentation.

I don't see why a link to the official documentation would "harm readability" or be "completely superfluous" and I thought I was in the scope of "add related resources or links" which is a recommended edit. One point my edit could be imporved is the edit summary that was quite short.

Would be happy to understand the reason behind the reject to avoid clobbing the review queue with edits that would ultimately be rejected.

Comment: My question is why you felt the need to edit a 4.5 year question by just adding a link to documentation. If you had "updated" the question with new methods to bring the answer up to date, I could have understood, but just adding the link to documentation on an antique answer, that anyone in the field can search with 3 words in google, is not a meaningful edit in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe the link to .NET 4.8 vs 3.5 quoted in the answer raised an eyebrow ? I don't really see a reason reason to reject it for that point. But bumping to the homepage  a 5 years old Q/A for just a link is a bit debatable.

Comment: I get the 4.8 vs 3.5 point. The documentation linked applies to 3.5 too (as noted at the bottom of the page) but I should have put it in the edit summary as it's not clear from the edit itself.

Comment: It is worth noting that also spammers include links in posts by suggesting edits, so it might be that the reviewers are also careful in accepting adding a link. Additionally you could argue why you only added a link for select but not for ToArray. That would have made it complete. I personally don't think I would have rejected that edit  but I can see why some reviewers don't go soft on just adding a link. Also if they just looked at the rendered view and not at the actual markdown they might have wondered what changed. Only your edit comment should have triggered them in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a bit of a gamble to get your suggested edits accepted. In most cases you have the robo-reviewers on your side who will accept any edit you throw at them. But the review audit system makes them sometimes pay attention, leading to rejection of edits that seem to do no harm. Also spammers tend to add only links to posts so that might also steer a reviewer in the wrong direction.

I do think adding links to official documentation in answers should be welcomed, if those links indeed support the answer. I don't fancy seeing answers where every keyword is linked to official documents or a wikipedia article. That is useless.

In this specific case adding the links seemed beneficial as the question explicitly asked for an equivalent construct in C# for something that exists in JavaScript. If you do add links to older posts do keep an eye on if you're linking to the correct version. I don't expect public interfaces of C# implementations that live in assemblies that are part of the framework to change overnight but you can't be to careful.

Looking at that suggested edit and the answer I wonder if you shouldn't have also linked to the docs for `ToArray`. And make the edit comment a bit more prominent / extended but only to trigger the reviewers, not because you're doing a lazy job.

If you try to be as complete as possible with your edits and add a tad more description to what value you added to a post I expect more of such edits would be accepted but I wouldn't be surprised if you're hitting a rejection now and then. That is unfortunately a bit part of the suggested edit game.

It is worth mentioning that this is what a not careful reviewer might see, if they picked the wrong view:

#### Rendered output

[image]

Looking at that a reviewer might not notice that the other view really reviews the added value of your edit:

#### Markdown

[image]

which makes more clear what has changed.

Feel free to hop in chat if you have any inquiries or need advice over your suggested edits.

Answer (score -10):

Extending a bit from my comment:

While adding links to documentation is a good practice in itself, it has to be weighted about the consequence of an edit.

In this case the question is nearly 5 years old, this edit would bump it to the front page, bringing more people to check what has changed to find just a link to documentation which can be taken as an useless bump.

So overall, if you don't have a new alternative to add and your edit consist only of a link to general documentation, pay attention to the post age to avoid this kind of "more annoying than useful" bumps.

It's a matter of balance between the value added to the post and the cost it has by bumping it, use your best judgement :)

Comment: I rarely browse SO and was not aware that the edits would bump the question up. And yeah, didn't check the age of the question as I didn't thought it would have any impact on the usefullness of the edit. How would you balance the fact that older question are more popular and therefore even a simple edit can save little time to a lot of people?

Comment: The age of the post is irrelevant when judging the quality of an edit. Either the edit was good and improved the post, or it wasn't. This is true for "suggested" edits and for edits performed by users with full edit privileges.

Comment: @yivi I agree post age is irrelevant, but I wouldn't say it's as simple as *"Either the edit was good and improved the post, or it wasn't."*, an edit can improve a post, but it can still be a poor edit and a waste of time for reviewers, such as in this case, why bother adding a documentation link when your favourite search engine is just as good.

Comment: @NickA I disagree. I believe supporting links are good and useful. And if an edit improves a post, and the post is not otherwise unsalvageable, I don't believe the reviewers should be so picky. They are volunteering their time in the same way than the editor.

Comment: @yivi Fair enough :), personally I wouldn't approve it, but I wouldn't reject it either, i'd skip and let the wave of robo-reviewers behind me decide what to do

Comment: @yivi well, seems like you should post a counter answer instead of this comment then :) I always weight the benefit/cost of an edit, I never really agreed on the doc links are worthwhile edits, but that's the actual consensus so I based myself on that

Comment: Not posting an answer because I can't really say why these reviewers reviewed the way they did. Can't tell. If I encountered this edit I would have skipped, since I don't know enough to judge if the link is really appropriate and pertinent. But I do have an opinion on saying "we should discourage edits to old posts" and on giving too much importance to "question bumping" in a site that receives thousands of questions per day, that's all.

Comment: Ok fair point, I just thought it was a good counter point of mine and did worth an answer of its own about edits in general :)

Comment: Atwood characterizes SO as a type of Wiki rather than a forum.  If minor edits are discouraged because they "bump" a post, perhaps then the UI of the site shouldn't do that.  I've given up any hope that SO will ever see significant UI changes though.

Comment: OK, let's say the edit is approved. This bumps the post to the front page. And that's bad. Yet it just [begs the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question) "why is bumping the post bad?". Isn't it possibly good - somebody might come in and offer a new perspective in the form of a new answer. Or maybe somebody will come up with a new question inspired from the existing posts. Is that *bad*? Why is bad for people to see content that's not current? Aren't people who land on posts from web searches *doing this all the time*? Is it bad for them, too?

Comment: @VLAZ there's a fair difference to ending on something after a search and having it coming up in a feed because of a "trivial" update. As I said that's a matter of balance, if there's indeed something new, that's good. For something with already 6 answers, the added benefit vs the wasted time of tag follower is debatable in my opinion

Comment: Yet the assumption was that all bumps are bad if they don't bring up new information. I challenge that assumption. The post *could be new information*.  Or could spawn other posts that can be valuable.

Comment: @VLAZ I thought "to find just a link to documentation which can be taken as an useless bump." made that clear I was talking of the specific case here of just a link to documentation in a old answer. That's not all bumps.

Comment: As I said - "all bumps are bad **if they don't bring up new information**". That's your premise, no? Or is it only specifically this one edit which doesn't bring up new information, but another edit that equally doesn't could be good? Well, whatever the case, I challenge the assumption that a *good* edit should not be done to an old question.

Comment: @VLAZ no that's not my premise: what I said is adding link to arcane/hard to find docs is really worthy, trivial to find link are more debatable and require to weight the usefulness. The problem is maybe that what you and I consider a "good" edit differ? I'd say this one is not substantial enough to worth the bump. My answer is all about that "weighting" but probably badly worded somehow if you read it as "minor bumps shouldn't be done on old posts"

Comment: Let's re-frame this, then - if that post was from *yesterday* and you saw the same edit made on it - would you approve it? If yes - then it's a good edit. If no - then it's not.

Comment: @VLAZ sincerely, I'd reject. While the help center recommend adding links, it also says "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged", this one qualify as Trivial and tiny IMHO. On a recent edit I would check the link to gauge it or skip if the subject is out of my  knowledge to judge the link as "link addition are ok in themselves" is the consensus I remember but disagree with.