# Is there a problem that reviewers approve/reject changes where they don't know the subject?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I would be very interested in hearing your thoughts on this. I really want to contribute to Stack Overflow but find it difficult to understand what is considered a good contribution.

I have made a total of three edits the last 18 months. Two have been rejected and one approved. At the time I did not have the reputation to make comments, edits were my only option.

I got my first rejection about 18 months ago and that really discouraged me from making any more edits, even though I am using Stack Overflow extensively and have found many errors that I would have wanted to correct with an edit (or comment).

In my opinion all three edits I made should have been approved (otherwise I would not have made them) but maybe I am wrong. 
Would be interested in hearing your opinion on this.

My edits:

1. Changed wrong code/typo that referenced non-existing function getLastInsertedId, should be getLastInsertId. 
   My edit was rejected but the reviewer instead added that edit himself ("Reject and Edit"), so post was corrected as I suggested but I got rejection...
   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21043631
2. Clarified that scss definitions need to be inserted before :root element.
   One reviewer that rejected said that this was intended to "to address the author of the post" and the other "Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."
   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25311551
3. Approved edit: Corrected a typo, changed .cscc to .scss. 
   IMO this edit was the one of the three that was least valuable. Probably most readers would anyway understand that it was just a typo and should be scss. 
   But at the same time, this was probably the easiest to approve for reviewers, since it does not require as much specific knowledge as for the two rejected edits (not that they were that advanced either). 
   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25311505

Comment: The first edit not only corrected the typo, but for some reason changed the link to the documentation? Instead of being on the word [here] you made the URL explicit. Was there a reason for that? Just trying to get around the 6 character limit?

Comment: @yivi I cannot remember now, but probably as you say to get around the character limit.

Comment: The second edit adds content from some other answer without proper attribution in the answer itself. It is noted in the edit message though, but should be in the question body.

Comment: That's a good way to get suggested edits rejected. The reviewer sees an unnecessary change and rejects to be on the safe side. Do not introduce noise to get around the character limit. I you can't find anything else to fix, just comment and leave it for someone else.

Comment: @yivi Got it. At the time I did not have enough rep to comment otherwise that would have been my first option. But my point is that I believe that I had a valid edit that would contribute to the answer. And obviously the reviewer thought so too as he added it but still rejected. The problem I think is that this discourages users like me from making useful contributions.

Comment: Just play within the rules, and you'll be discouraged less often. Adding noise to bypass a limit is a way to be discouraged. A piece of advise: until you hit 2k, it's better to focus on edits that correct spelling, grammar, remove noise, fix links and obvious typos. These do not need subject matter expertise, and are easier to review.

Comment: @maxfloden: **Parts** of your edit were good and should be accepted. The reviewer can't accept parts of an edit and reject other parts. If you really need to circumvent the character limit, there would have been better ways. For example, all sentences in the answer should start with a capitalized letter.

Comment: @BDL If that would have been given as a reason for rejection, that would have been something I would understand and could learn from. I did put it in the edit description as I was not sure if it was something that should be added or not. (My wild guess is that another reviewer could just as well have thought I should not add that credit and rejected the edit for that reason)

Comment: @yivi Thanks but I think the problem (in general, not directly related to this question) is that, to reach 2k you have to be really devoted to getting rep. Users with high rep are of course super important contributors to SO. But I believe SO also need user like me: I don't want to fix spelling, grammar etc. just to gain rep. I search SO to find solutions to my problems, and when I find bits and pieces that are not completely correct, I wish to contribute with corrections and clarifications. SO has helped me so much and I just want to give a little back, but it I find it difficult.

Comment: That’s awesome. But there are rules to contribute. If you really want to contribute, my advise is to play with the system. It’s more fun (and more helpful) that way.

Comment: @BDL - Thanks for the clarification about not being able to approve parts, I was not aware of that. Just as reviewer in this case was able to "reject and edit" I would have thought it was possible to "approve and edit". In a funny way, the reason I changed the link to full url (edit A) was probably to make as little noise as possible but it was considered the other way around.

Comment: an answer I wrote a couple of days ago seems applicable here as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393592/578411

Comment: Well, the first rejection might have also been a wrong click, instead of Approve & Edit a Reject & Edit. That's sad for you but that sometimes happens.

Comment: A general observation: When I'm reviewing and someone makes a valid edit, an unnecessary one AND leaves lots of things *uncorrected* (spelling/grammar, usually) I will reject and edit, rather than improve the edit. There's been too much left for the next person who comes along to correct. This just to give you the POV of someone who spends time in that queue, in order to better understand that side of the equation; it's not meant to be a comment on the specific edits mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thx all for your comments and answers. My post was not to defend my edits, I just wanted to test my view on the review system. My (maybe premature) conclusion from this (incl that this post got downvoted to -3) is that this view is not shared by the rest of you. So SO will continue to be a good place for me to search for info but maybe not to contribute. I will be happy to share my knowledge but not to spend time to get 2k rep points or write things that have a bigger chance of being rejected than approved. But I am grateful to you who do spend that time and keep SO a great source of info.

Comment: (Meta-meta advice: I sometimes see questions here or on the main site that claim that the question being posted "is of interest to a lot of people". While that may be true, it is a guess at best, and people will read that and think "ah, this question is going to be on shaky ground, since it needs to be prefixed with appeals to pupported popularity". It is thus usually best not to add these because they invoke cynicism automatically. If you want to know the answer to a question, then that is enough justification to write it).

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a problem that reviewers approve/reject changes where they don't know the subject?

No, there is not. Suggested edit reviewers are not supposed to be subject matter experts.

Most suggested edits should deal with things a non-expert could review. If an edit requires subject matter expertise most often is better to either leave it for someone with full edit privileges (2k reputation), or even post another answer.

Never make unnecessary changes to bypass the 6 character limit. That's (rightfully) perceived as noise by reviewers: It requires additional review effort (the reviewer needs to make sure that the change is not actually harmful) and in the end you end up with change with no value.

Almost always there are other changes you can make on a post to improve it and go  over the 6 character limit. It's very rare that you can't find an actual 6 character improvement to make to any post.

Now and then an actually good edit will be rejected anyway. That's part of the game. We are dealing with a people-powered system, and people are known to make mistakes. If you stick to the rules and provide good, thorough, well informed suggested edits they will get approved much more often than not, and you'll be contributing to make the site better.

---

Additional feedback regarding your three edits:

1. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21043631) was probably rejected because of the unnecessary change to bypass to 6 character limit. The link change was not helpful. At best, it had no value.
2. Can't comment on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25311551). I would have skipped the review myself. Maybe it's a good edit, but in the end you are adding to the answer. It's very likely correct, but it's not a safe edit to make without full-edit privileges.

   Nevertheless, note that one of the users that rejected the edit is the answer author. In the end, the post author has (mostly) final say on what a post says. If they believe your edit didn't improve the question or simply disagreed with it, they are within their rights rejecting it. Even when you have full-edit privileges post-authors can rollback edits if they do not agree with them.
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25311505) one was approved (correctly), but it wasn't a **great** edit either. While correcting the `variables.cscc` typo you formatted the filename as code. That's good. But there are other instances of filenames or directory names that could have been formatted as code as well (`assets`, `xx.page.html`). And you left a "Regards" at the end of the question. Greetings and fluff should be removed from posts.

Comment: *people are known to make mistakes* ... we need more bots ...

Comment: But the bots are made by people. So you see, there is no escape. We need more monkeys. Monkeys are good.

Comment: On 2.  - one of the people who rejected was the original author of the post. I'd assume *they* are an expert in what goes in their answer. To me, the "before `root`" addition didn't make sense but I'm not even versed in the tech there. Perhaps the author thought it's either self-evident, or otherwise irrelevant addition. They do talk about `root` later on, so if I was writing something similar, I'd want to avoid jumping up and down to the same concept and just keep it in one point or *at the very least* talk about a point first, then reference it.

Comment: @VLAZ I didn't realize the post author rejected the suggested edit. I'll mention that in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @yivi honestly, I wouldn't have noticed if it wasn't for the background colour of the name...and even then, I had to check if it wasn't the *question author* instead (usually they have the bluish background, apparently it's "original post author" decoration. There were three people who voted, two of whom rejected, so it seemed like a normal review process with the majority winning. Instead, it seems that two people voted and the author *happened* to use their binding vote third...only the author is listed on top as if they voted first.

Answer (score -17):

Yivi has right that most edit review does not really require the knowledge of the subject. My subjective experience is that most of the suggested edits are obviously improvements, making it imho the easiest queue. Most of the rejected edits are clearly rejectable (trying to answer/comment the post, destructive or similar).

But, sometimes it really requires to understand, what exactly the user suggests. I think it is maybe 2-3% of all the cases. In these cases, the reviewers should think a little bit and click "Skip" if they are not sure. Sometimes they do that, sometimes don't.

Often, if suggested edits are rejected, contrary their clear improvements, is that the reviewers sometimes have an irrational urge to avoid the OP to get even this +2 reputation. It is hard to deal with it - the community should be changed. In my experience, it is hardly site-dependent, how antagonistic are the reviewers in the suggested edit queue. In my opinion, the SO is not so bad in this sense, but it still happens.

If you are *sure* that your suggested edit was falsely rejected (might be an overlook or this irrational antagonism I mentioned), then it is not so bad if you suggest it again. *Write a convincing edit comment, it helps a lot!* But never do it a third time.

Comment: I agree the community should change but I'm not sure if that should be done based on your guidance.

Comment: @rene My guidances have zero effect to anything. I only try to give psychological/emotional support to the people with whom we deal unfairly.

Comment: I need  psychological/emotional support due to the on-going bashing of reviewers.

Comment: That's why we suggest _"Downvote and move on"_, because interacting with this kind of bashing isn't productive.

Comment: *Most of the cases, if suggested edits are rejected, contrary their clear improvements, is that the reviewers sometimes have an irrational urge to avoid the OP to get even this +2 reputation.*: Some proof/data would be nice for such a statement. At least a proof that this happens sometimes (which I doubt) and then that this is the case **most of the time** (which I doubt even more). Assuming bad indent on any reviewer who doesn't agree with you is not nice.

Comment: @BDL I changed "most of the times" to "often". You are right, that I have no proof. Furthermore, if I would dig out a falsely rejected edit, then you would create some artifically generated reasoning, why the rejection was okay. And, even if you would admit that the rejection was false, I would still have no proof for the antagonism of the reviewers. But... I am here since many years ago, *I know you*, because *I am one of you*. And I know, what is the background. This is why I *must* state this, because I am sure and it is very important, despite that I have no proof.